# C# MySqlDataReader in MySqlDataReader

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqldatareader

In php I have something like that:

```
$zapytanie1 = "SELECT * FROM tabelka2";
$wykonaj1 = mysql_query($zapytanie1);
while($dane1 = mysql_fetch_array($wykonaj1))
{
$idzs = $dane1['id'];
$zapytanie2 = "SELECT * FROM tabelka2 WHERE dane=$idzs";
$wykonaj = mysql_query($zapytanie2);
while($dane2 = mysql_fetch_array($wykonaj2))
{
$nazwa = $dane2['name'];
}
echo $nazwa;
}
```

If I make something like that in C#:

```
    MySqlCommand zapytanieW = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from tabelka1", Polaczenie);
            MySqlDataReader drW = zapytanieW.ExecuteReader();
            while (drW.Read())
            {
                double id = Convert.ToDouble(drW["id"]);
   MySqlCommand zapytanieWZ = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from tabelka2 WHERE dane="+id+"", Polaczenie);
            MySqlDataReader drWZ = zapytanieWZ.ExecuteReader();
            while (drWZ.Read())
            {
                string nazwa = Convert.ToString(drW["nazwa"]);
}}
```

I get error:
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

But I cant closed first one.
How can I do somthing like in PHP example?

Comment: You need to read all rows of your first data reader before start an other. Or merge the two query in one with a `join`

Comment: I can't use join. Any other suggestions?

Comment: And with an old school  where clause ? `select * from T1, T2 where T1.T1_Id = T2.T1_Id`. You can also store store ids of first table into a list.

Comment: Old school. How it should be according to the new school?